# c++ skips a function?

Tags: c++

Can someone please help me figure out why the 'Paycheck combineChecks' function is not doing anything? It just skips right over it. When I run it just ends after printing out and doesn't do any of the combine checks function. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yep, the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) strikes again.

Comment: It's not just that; even if he wanted to just call `combineChecks` in `main` he doesn't have the parameters set up to do that.

Comment: Why was this question so heavily downrated? It's clear, it's a well scoped specific problem, and it provides well formatted and easy to follow code.

Comment: Thanks @JBentley , I left some comments below -- any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Paycheck combineChecks(Paycheck p1, Paycheck p2);
```

...is not a *call* to a function, but a [*forward declaration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

It basically just means "compiler, assume that somewhere there is function defined with this signature that you can use later".

EDIT: To actually call the function, to start with you need two paychecks to combine that you can pass in, let's call them `paycheck1` and `paycheck2`, then just do;

```
Paycheck combined = combineChecks(paycheck1, paycheck2);
```

Comment: I need to use the function called 'Paycheck combineChecks(Paycheck p1, Paycheck p2). Thanks.

Comment: @user22507 What part of my edit that tells you how to call it is unclear?

Comment: "    Paycheck combined = combineChecks(Paycheck p1, Paycheck p2);" I get the error 'expected primary-expression before p1 and p2.

Comment: @user22507 First, you need to have two paychecks to combine, since the method takes two paychecks as parameters. Second, if you have two actual paychecks stored in p1 and p2, the call should be `Paycheck combined = combineChecks(p1, p2);`.

Comment: OK thanks. So first I 'initializePaycheck(p1);' and 'initializePaycheck(p2);' and then i can    combineChecks(Paycheck p1, Paycheck p2);?

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() {
    // ...
    Paycheck combineChecks(Paycheck p1, Paycheck p2);
```

The last line of code there *declares* a function called `combineChecks` that takes two arguments of type `Paycheck` and returns another `Paycheck` object by value. That is **not** an *invokation* of the function.

Comment: Thanks David, what do I need to do to make the paycheck function start?

Comment: @user22507: That has already be handled by Joachim.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an invocation:

```
 combineChecks(Paycheck p1, Paycheck p2);
```

but is a redeclaration of the function (it is already declared above `main()`). I am not sure what to suggest to change to as there is only one instance of `Paycheck`, called `pay`, in the program and that function requires two. It also returns a `Paycheck` instance which would need to be used.

Comment: Hi hmjd, I need to use these two different functions, not sure how to call it from main and have it run.

Comment: @user22507 See Joachim Isaksson's answer (recently edited) for how to correctly call your function.